# how to extaract data from indiexpo about a user in node js?

Tags: node.js

I'm making a node js bot that need to get data grom indiexpo, by accessing the rank and the level of a user, that by a normal person can be accesed my going to https://www.indiexpo.net/en/users/[user-name] (ex. https://www.indiexpo.net/en/users/freank ), the website it self desn't have any api that you can use to acses it via code so i think i will have to extract the numbers from the html file thta is generated when gong to those links.

I've already tried cheerio, but because of the complex structure of the website and the non dinstinction by name of the interessed object it makes my life very difficult.

```
i don't have any code yet . . .
```

in the case of the example user thta i've linked the values returned shoude be:

```
level: 12
rank: 14
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Consider doing a get request on the said page and then using body-parser to extract the required data . Check out [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)  and [body parser module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

Comment: @RishiC could you be a bit more explicit with the boy pase part, please?

Comment: When you do a GET request on an html page, the output is the html code to the page itself. The "level" and "rank" would be a part of a div. What you can do is, when you get the code of the html page, search for the div which contains this information. You can do it without body-parser as well, by using string manipulation , but the body-parser module has functions built into it specially for these kind of actions

Comment: I managed to run a code without using body parser which seems to work. I am posting it in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the node module `request` for it and then do some String manipulation. I tested out this code and it gave me the correct level and rank as mentioned in the question

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://www.indiexpo.net/en/users/freank', function(error,response,body){
    var L_count = body.indexOf("Level: ")+7
    var R_count = body.indexOf("Rank: ")+6
    var level = ""
    var rank = ""
    while(!isNaN(body.charAt(L_count))){
        level+=body.charAt(L_count);
        L_count ++;
    }
    while(!isNaN(body.charAt(R_count))){
        rank+=body.charAt(R_count)
        R_count ++
    }
    console.log(level);
    console.log(rank);
})
```

I don't know if there is a more efficient way to do it, this is the most efficient one I could think of which used string manipulation

(PS: Note that `body` here is the html code of the page)